# Creating graphs in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have three listviews in VB.net and i want to get common values from that and make an custom chart from it
For Example,
Eg.

```
Listview1  Listview2  Listview3
A          B          H
B          C          B
C          A          D
D          E          E
E          J          F
```

Common in Listview

```
1 And 2    2 And 3   1 And 3
A          B         B
B          E         D
C                    E
E
```

Then Create Graph shown like this
[image: Diagram]

I know how to get common values but don't know how to draw graph like this

Any ideas or Suggestions . . . . .??
It's VB Forms Application

Comment: What is your GUI environment? Forms? WPF? Web?

Comment: @Ceres It's VB Forms Application . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using [Graph#](https://graphx.codeplex.com) You'll find enough documentation And tutorials there

Comment: Hmmm very Good . . . .

Answer (score 1):

There is a chart tool where you can add your values and plot in various styles

Here's a simple example of creating a line graph with a single series containing 3 data points.

Drag a chart to your form and add this code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     Chart1.Series.Clear()
     Chart1.Titles.Add("Demo")
     'Create a new series and add data points to it.
     Dim s As New Series
     s.Name = "aline"
     'Change to a line graph.
     s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
     s.Points.AddXY("1990", 27)
     s.Points.AddXY("1991", 15)
     s.Points.AddXY("1992", 17)
     'Add the series to the Chart1 control.
     Chart1.Series.Add(s)
 End Sub
```

You will need to add

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
```

Of course you would have to iterate through your data and add points based on your information.

Comment: No buddy i'm looking for chart drawing like This http://i.stack.imgur.com/NDEox.gif

Comment: You know which type of chart is this?